# Can I override a list value with a new list, natively in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'd like to use the [list data type](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) in Redis, but I'd like to simply override/set the list with a value instead of interacting with it in push/pop fashion.

For my business case, I need the queryable nature of a list, but need to set/override the entire list.

Is this possible with native Redis commands?

(Not thread safe, but I can delete the key and then use [LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush)). Perhaps this could be wrapped in a Lua Script if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Your best bet for a secure and nice solution would be to use a Lua script, or a transaction, to make sure it's executed as an atomic operation. One possible option could be:

```
MULTI
DEL my_list
RPUSH my_list "A" "B" "C"
EXEC
```

If you're using expiration for the key, before removing it you could read the remaining expiry time with `TTL my_list`.

Comment: I haven't been able to test this - as I took a different direction with the code, but marking this as the answer since it confirms that there is no native functionality built-in, and a Lua script would need to be used.